# What is the maximum number of particles that can be arranged so that each one touches every other one?

Tags: geometry, spheres, combinatorial-geometry

What is the maximum value of $n$ for which we can arrange $n$ particles in such a way that each particle touches every $n-1$ remaining particles in 3-dimensional space? A "particle" is a sphere of extremely small size. My friend and I think that the set of values of $n$ satisfying this condition is $\{1,2,3,4\}$. Are we correct or wrong?

Comment: Points cannot touch each other, except (maybe) if they are the same point.

Comment: @David please see the edited version.

Comment: So, "particles" means "spheres, all of the same size"?

Comment: I suspect this is a poorly worded way to ask which complete graphs (all pairs of vertices are connected by a graph's edge) are planar (can be represented by a drawing in the plane where edges intersect only at vertices).  That would account for your friend's thought that four vertices are possible.

Comment: @David Yes,they all are identical.

Comment: @hardmath  would you please elaborate or quote it as an answer?

Comment: @hardmath: I suspect, rather, that the question is asking for complete graphs where each vertex is *equidistant* from the others. If so, then one must *think outside the plane* to accommodate four vertices (making this a fairly well-known puzzle).

Comment: @Unique:  please see the comments and clarify what you mean by particle and touching.  The answer depends on what you are asking.

Comment: Could you maybe find an abstraction for the particle term for physically illiterates like myself? e.g. do you want equal size circles/balls, do you want a graph as suggested by @hardmath, or something else entirely?

Comment: Arrange them where? The plane, 3D space? If the dimension is high enough any $n$ is possible, see [simplex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex).

Comment: @Conifold please see the edited version.

Comment: @Dirk I have now defined particle in the edited version.

Comment: You are right for the 3D case assuming rigid spheres. "Graph" was used here not in the sense of graphing functions, but in the sense of [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory), vertices represent "particles" and edges "touching". Your rigid model means straight line edges. Without that (plastic stretchable particles) any graph can be embedded into 3D space, so arbitrary $n$ is possible.

Comment: @Conifold Can we obtain a general formula  for doing such problems in any dimensions?

Comment: For the rigid case the maximum is $n+1$ in $n$ dimensions, the configuration is given by the $n$-dimensional simplex. For the non-rigid case only 2D case is interesting, the maximum is $n=4$ by the [Kuratowski theorem on planar graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_theorem). All complete graphs for $n>4$ are non-planar.

Comment: Now that I think of it, $4$ can be increased to $5$ even in the rigid 3D case if we allow particles of different size. Put the four equal spheres into the tetrahedral configuration. There will be a hollow space in the middle, and one can inscribe one more small sphere into it that touches all of them. I can't think of a way to put in touch more than $5$, even of different sizes, but one would have to prove it to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have n spheres with each known radius r.

Now if you want to make all n spheres touch, look at (n-1)-dimensional triangles with edge length 2r and the spheres on the vertices.

By that I mean, for n=1, you just have a lone sphere, touching nothing.
For n=2, imagine a line that is connecting both spheres.
For n=3, imagine a triangle where each sphere is connecting to the other two.
Now, for n=4, imagine a tetrahedral, where still every sphere touches each other.

For n=5, you would need a 4-dimensional space, but if I understand correctly, you only have 3 dimensions to work with, so n=4 would be your maximum.

Comment: Thanks, can we generalise this result in the form of a formula?

Comment: @Unique You can generalise to the number of dimensions you are able to work with. If you have k dimensions to work with, n=k+1 is the maximum number of spheres that fulfills your requirements. Its hard to imagine 4-dimensional triangles, but the reasoning will still be the same.